# How can I fix my title page to conform to APA standards?

Tags: titles, apa-style

Here is the code for my document:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{1in}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{redacted}
\chead{}
\rhead{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\title{redacted}
\author{redacted}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

My issue is that I cannot make the title page display the header that I have defined. How do I fix this? As a side remark, should I be formatting this differently if I want to conform to [APA guidelines](http://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/01/)?

P.S. It may or may not be relevant that I am creating this on Ubuntu. If any of you suggest that I install a particular package, please give me a quick tutorial explaining how. I don't entirely understand how Ubuntu processes packages.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\maketitle` in the standard classes always does `\thispagestyle{empty}` so you don't get the standard page heading on the opening page. If you do want the standard heading perhaps the simplest is to just locally define `\thispagestyle` to do nothing. (An alternative being to use the `fancyhdr` syntax to redefine the empty page style to be less empty.)

```
{\def\thispagestyle#1{}
\maketitle}
```

Produces a title with the page header defined for normal pages.